# Time derivative of $\frac{d\gamma}{d\dot{x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Is there a good rule of thumb or some way to better remember this? I always seem to forget how to take the derivative of a derivative when it is in the *general form* $\frac{d\gamma}{d\dot{x}}$. If I had the actual values, I could easily see what the time derivative is, but for some reason I don't know how to express $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial\dot{x}})$.

Comment: What is $\gamma$?

Comment: @Javi $\gamma=\gamma(\dot{x})$. That's all that I know about $\gamma$.

Comment: I guess $x=x(t)$. I would use the chain rule. $\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial\dot{x}}$ is again a function of $\dot{x}$. Then, $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial\dot{x}})=\frac{\partial^2\gamma}{\partial\dot{x}^2}\cdot \frac{d\dot{x}}{dt}$